# simulating iphone on windows?

Tags: iphone, windows, xcode, macos

Is there any way to test my objective-c code on windows..

is there any ide like xcode for windows to develop iphone applications.

Answer (score 4):

I love apple, and the iPhone, and I program on Mac OS X but I do not get why Windows developers shouldn't be allowed to develop for the iPhone. Okay I get it, Objective-C is an Apple thing, but still.. It's C based, how hard can it be?

Comment: I totally agree with this. The majority of iPhone owners do not have Apple computers. I would assume that there are far more iPhone users with Windows PC's than there are with Apple Mac's.

Comment: But all that is required is for all iPhone developers to have a Mac. I get this but I mean porting an entire IDE to Windows is not a small thing. What wouild be more realistic I think is if Apple would allow you to install Mac OS X in a VM, perhaps with a special license and so forth. That's an easier technical hurdle to climb anyway.

Comment: #TechBoy It's not about users, it's about developers. I think computer use of people able to write iPhone programs who own a mac is more split in favour of Mac. Even than it's possibly less than half but at the end of the day, this is probably a strategic decision by Apple. Remeber that they do sell Macs and don't make any money off Xcode - especially not a PC version.

Comment: Would it not be a 'hurdle' to port OS X to a VM? There is a thing called 'hackintosh', but seriously, that is nothing compared to Mac OS X on a real Mac.. Besides, Apple wants to guarantee their product, and they can not do such a thing on a 'regular' PC with strange hardware, and I can not blame them for that.

A solution would be not to use Objective-C for the iPhone, but it is a great language, so that's not an option either. We're stuck ;-)

Comment: Well, the reality is that this requirement is not hampering iPhone development so I don't think it is high on Apple's priority list. Probably doing some manuevering to get away from AT&T exclusivity would help them a lot more!

Comment: The OS X development kit for Windows Mobile is where again?

Comment: Kendall, you are right of course, but what OS X developer in his right mind would think of developing for Windows Mobile?! *lol*

Comment: The is one and only one reason why apple does not allow people to write iphone apps using non apple computers, to use their phone dominance to suck in as much money as they can. They don't care about developers or the iphone owners they just want everything setup so they have maximum control and then use that control to make  money off things that are usually much cheaper or free. Also objective c is not an apple thing, it was created entirely independent of apple.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Indeed, you need the latest version of Xcode (that only runs on the latest Mac OS X) with Objective-C 2.0 even to do iPhone development.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna write something on Obj-C, you can use GCC.
Anyway you may only try to create something with third party toolkits, if you wanna native iphone dev. env. use hackintosh or buy mac :)

Comment: Well, yes but I'm not sure if GCC supports Objective-C 2.0. Nevertheless, you won't have access to the APIs or the SDK. But yes, the hackintosh stuff is correct. :0

Comment: You need some special add-on for gcc, but it should work.

Comment: Of course Objective-C is supported by GCC.  It was supported even before APple started using it, and these days any improvement made by Apple to GCC is included back in GCC.

You are right about the lack of libraries being an issue.

Comment: Objective-C is supported by gcc, but Objective-C 2.0 is not. You can't compile a class with an @property declaration with gcc 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test some basic not iPhone relevant objective-c code, you also could use [GNUStep](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnustep/). But in my opinion its not really stable.