# iPhone App Doubt

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [simulating iphone on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780864/simulating-iphone-on-windows)

I have my iPhone.
I am eager to make my own iPhone app. But had some doubts,

1. Is it necessary to have a Apple computer to make an iPhone app ?
2. Is their any IDE used to make this appln development ? Is that IDE available for Windows ?

Thanks,
Rajon

Comment: If you had google'd then you would have got many related questions with top answers on the same topic.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. Xcode.  Mac OS X only.

joe

Comment: Can I not make iPhone app on Windows computer and then deploy the same on iPhone ?

Comment: No.  The IDE and SDK are only available for Mac OS X.  Not Windows.

Comment: @Rajon - No, you can not develop an iPhone app in Windows.  You can write the code in whatever you want but compiling, testing, and exporting to a phone is impossible without XCode (Mac OS X only).

Comment: What about iPad appln ? Can I make it on Windows ?

Comment: I heard that iPhone appln can be built using Adobe Flash (Flash Professional CS5) ? Is it true ? So that I can install Flash Pro CS5 on Windows and start working ..

Comment: iPad and iPhone both use iOS, and you need Xcode and Mac OS X to do that.  Flash does not run on iOS at all.  Adobe was working on something that would translate Flash to an iOS application, but I have no idea how good it works, or if it's even available yet.  If the pricing of the tools is typical for Adobe, it would be cheaper to buy a used Mac mini and use that for your development.  Xcode is free.

Answer (score 1):

If your are looking for an answer said: "Yes, you can develop an iOS application using Windows PC", here it is.

You can develop for iOS using Adobe Flash Professional. Which do have a Windows Version.

And Apple has changed their rules now, that means you can also submit your App made by Adobe Flash Professional to App Store.

Good News, right?

Comment: Tell me how ? Bcz I am working on Windows platform... Any links in support of your answer ?

Comment: You can Google, or go to the link: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

Comment: I heard that iPhone appln can be built using Adobe Flash (Flash Professional CS5) ? Is it true ? So that I can install Flash Pro CS5 on Windows and start working ..

Comment: I doubt you can develop iOS apps on windows