# Is Xcode available for Windows 10?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, winforms, ide

I was going to start learning the Swift programming language, and for that, I was going to install Xcode. But I found out that Xcode is only available for macOS, and I have a computer that uses Windows. Is there any way to get Xcode or any software on which I can code in Swift language? Is there any other IDE for Swift other than Xcode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simulating iphone on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780864/simulating-iphone-on-windows)

Comment: try google search for "run swift code on web". you will get the online swift play-ground links. You can not create full app, but you can practice the swift coding...

Comment: A common way to start off with a Windows pc is [MacStadium](https://www.macstadium.com/).

Comment: swift is available for [linux](https://swift.org/download/#releases) so one option is to run linux on a virtual machine

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The xcode swoftware is only available on MacOS. There is a lot of online IDE where you can code in swift like [this one](https://iswift.org/playground). But with this kind of tool you wont be able to create a user interface. **It is not possible to create a user interface on any other operating system than MacOS**. If you really want to create an application with a user interface then you can always [setup a virtual machine](https://techsprobe.com/install-macos-catalina-virtualbox-windows/) with MacOS running on it, install Xcode and start coding ;)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was hoping to not having to use virtual machine for this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not support Swift on Windows, but if you consider third party products, then RemObjects has Silver free of charge,

https://www.remobjects.com/elements/silver/

You can install it and write Swift projects in Visual Studio or its own Water IDE.

[image]

Silver enables you to write Swift programs that connect to other programming frameworks (for example, Windows and Android), so you will find it an interesting approach to go.